# X-Frame-Options Issue Only When Logged into Multiple G-Mail Accounts Simultaneously

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I am logged in to lets say my personal gmail account on our work domain and run a script within Google Sheets that pops up a `ui.showmodaldialog` with embedded html it works exactly as expected. The issue is people often need to log into a different email account within the work domain. When they click their icon and switch to this other account and then run the exact same script, it refuses to display because of the X-Frames-Options policy. The user can rerun the same script from their personal account they were logged into originally and it will still work just fine.

It only appears to work from whatever email account they were originally logged into and not from any additional accounts you log into thereafter. If they logged into the work email account on the domain first and then their personal one second, it will only work on the work account and not their personal account (on the same domain). This seems like it is an issue with the Google Suite. It is not browser dependent.

Any ideas on if there is a way to correct this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Try using another browser for the second account. I mainly use Chrome but in situations where I want two accounts open I also use Firefox.

Comment: To add to Cooper's answer, you can also use browsers built using Chrome's engine such as Opera and Brave.

Comment: Thanks. That would work for me individually, however, there are hundreds of users and most will refuse to do this. So it is not a viable solution. I have found this thread: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374 and looks like it is being worked on. I will update here if any solutions are found.