# Access not allowed to Google Apps Script form

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-account

I have created a script, via Apps Script, and published it in such a way that anyone, even anonymous, can access it. I have the problem that, if there are more than one authenticated session in the same browser, the access to the script is forbidden even if no authentication is required. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66780096/1595451

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66491971/1595451 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256242/1595451